# Gradle plugin extension and enum types

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I'm creating a gradle plugin with a custom extension :

```
project.extensions.create("myExtension", MyExtension.class)
```

Where MyExtension looks like :

```
class MyExtension {
  Set<MyEnum> mySet;
  MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to set `mySet` inside my build.gradle (with standard DSL) :

```
myExtension {
    myEnum = 'enumField1'
    mySet = ['enumField1']
}
```

I get a `java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyEnum` only for mySet, the String to enum convertion works well for myEnum... So I'm gessing if it is possible for a Collection of enum type ? Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it to work by using a simple java array instead of generic `Collection<T>` :

```
class MyExtension {
  // string convertion doesn't work
  Set<MyEnum> mySet;
  // string convertion works fine
  MyEnum[] myArray;
  MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

The extension can then be used as expected :

```
myExtension {
    myEnum = 'enumField1'
    mySet = ['enumField1']
}
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

It works for `myEnum` because Groovy automatically converts strings assigned to enum properties. To make the same work for `mySet`, you'll have to add a method to the extension that accepts a string, converts it to the corresponding enum value (a simple cast will do in Groovy), and adds the latter to the set. You'll also have to initialize the set.

Comment: will groovy convert ['enumField1'] properly if the target attribute is a java array of MyEnum[] ?

Comment: I don't think it will, but it's easy to test.

Comment: If this answers your question, then please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: will try the array thing before